# Why is my Inner Join query not returning anything?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have two tables Workouts and Exercises. I'm trying to fetch all exercises with the workout_id that matches the Workout we clicked on. I've made an Inner Join query but it does not seem to return anything. Is there something wrong with my query?

I'm using SQLite to create my database. I've checked to make sure there are exercises in the Exercises table there is and they have a workout_id.

My query:

```
    @Nullable
@Override
public Cursor query(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable String[] projection, @Nullable String selection, @Nullable String[] selectionArgs, @Nullable String sortOrder) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = null;
    int match = uriMatcher.match(uri);
    switch (match){
        case WORKOUT:
            cursor = db.query(WorkoutContract.WorkoutEntry.TABLE_NAME_WORKOUT,projection,selection,selectionArgs,null,null,sortOrder);
            break;
        case WORKOUT_ID:
            selection = WorkoutContract.WorkoutEntry._ID + "=?";
            selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(ContentUris.parseId(uri))};
            cursor = db.query(WorkoutContract.WorkoutEntry.TABLE_NAME_WORKOUT,projection,selection,selectionArgs,null,null,sortOrder);
            break;
        case EXERCISE:
            cursor = db.query(WorkoutContract.WorkoutEntry.TABLE_NAME_EXERCISES,projection,selection,selectionArgs,null,null,sortOrder);
            break;
        case EXERCISE_ID:
            selection = WorkoutContract.WorkoutEntry._ID + "=?";
            selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(ContentUris.parseId(uri))};
            cursor = db.query(WorkoutContract.WorkoutEntry.TABLE_NAME_EXERCISES,projection,selection,selectionArgs,null,null,sortOrder);
            break;
        case WORkOUT_EXERCISE:
            final String QUERY = "SELECT workouts._id, " +
                    "exercise_name," +
                    "weight," +
                    "reps," +
                    "rpe"+
                    " FROM "+
                    "exercises"+
                    " INNER JOIN workouts ON workouts._id = exercises.workout_id"+
                    " WHERE workouts._id=1";
           cursor = db.rawQuery(QUERY, null);
            break;

        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Failed to retrieve" + uri);
    }
    cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(),uri);
    int rowcount = cursor.getCount();
    Log.d("ROWCOUNT","Number of rows = " + String.valueOf(rowcount));
    return cursor;    }
```

My tables:

```
String CREATE_TABLE_WORKOUTS = "CREATE TABLE " + WorkoutContract.WorkoutEntry.TABLE_NAME_WORKOUT + " ("
            + WorkoutContract.WorkoutEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
            + WorkoutContract.WorkoutEntry.WORKOUT_TITLE + " STRING, "
            + WorkoutContract.WorkoutEntry.WORKOUT_DATE + " STRING" + ")";

    String CREATE_TABLE_EXERCISES = "CREATE TABLE " + WorkoutContract.WorkoutEntry.TABLE_NAME_EXERCISES + " ("
            + WorkoutContract.WorkoutEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
            + WorkoutContract.WorkoutEntry.EXERCISE_NAME  + " STRING, "
            + WorkoutContract.WorkoutEntry.REPS + " INTEGER, "
            + WorkoutContract.WorkoutEntry.RPE + " INTEGER, "
            + WorkoutContract.WorkoutEntry.WEIGHT + " INTEGER, "
            + WorkoutContract.WorkoutEntry.WORKOUT_ID + " INTEGER, "
            + "FOREIGN KEY"+"("+ WorkoutContract.WorkoutEntry.WORKOUT_ID+")" + " REFERENCES "
            + WorkoutContract.WorkoutEntry.TABLE_NAME_WORKOUT
            +"("
            +(WorkoutContract.WorkoutEntry._ID) +")" +")";
```

I expect the cursor to return some exercises with the corresponding workout_id but I don't seem to get anything back. No errors occur just an empty list.

**FIXED**

1)I was pointing to the wrong URI in the MainActivity, so I changed that.

```
Uri uri = withAppendedId(WorkoutContract.WorkoutEntry.CONTENT_URI, id);

Uri uri = withAppendedId(WorkoutContract.WorkoutEntry.JOIN_TABLE_URI, id);
```

2) Back inside my WorkoutProvider class I set the selectionArgs to:

```
 selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(ContentUris.parseId(uri))};
```

and passed that into my rawQuery.

```
cursor = db.rawQuery(QUERY, selectionArgs);
```

Comment: First thing to check is what **`WorkoutContract.WorkoutEntry.WORKOUT_ID`** is resolving to. To do this put a breakpoint on the line `cursor = db.rawQuery(QUEREY, selectionArgs);` and run in debug mode. Perhaps edit your question to include the result.

Comment: If the value appears to be as expected add two lines after the rawquery e.g. `int rowcount = cursor.getCount();` and `Log.d("ROWCOUNT","Number of rows = " + String.valueOf(rowcount)`, run in debug mode with breakpoint at 2nd line and see if rowcount is greater than 0. if not edit your question with actual data from the db.

Comment: Hey, Mike all it's returning is a String "workout_id" which isn't what I need. So I guess my real question is how do I get the actual Id of the workout to pass into the selectionArgs?

Comment: Ooops shouldv'e seen `WorkoutContract.WorkoutEntry.WORKOUT_ID ` onviously being the column name. You need to somehow get the actual id, As a test you could hard code the value 1 (quite likely to work). Otherwise the code above isn't enough to determine. You'd need to look at how you are invoking the method that the code above is. Perhaps edit your question to include.

Comment: @MikeT Hey Mike I hardcoded the 1 and the app returned the expected "Exercises" I've also added the full method above as you requested.

Comment: Do the other queries for the other cases all work as expected?

Comment: @MikeT Yes sir I've used all but 'EXERCISE_ID' just because I haven't gotten that far in my app to use it yet.

Comment: Writing more comprehensive answer.

Comment: @MikeT saw the code and making some tweaks to it. I'll get back to you tomorrow to let you know how it goes. I'm at work and my shift is almost over so it's time to go home. Thanks for all your help Mike I really appreciate the help! I'll keep you updated I think we're very close to solving it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you are effectively saying `..... WHERE workouts._id = '_id'` as you have `selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(WorkoutContract.WorkoutEntry.WORKOUT_ID)};`

and that **WorkoutContract.WorkoutEntry.WORKOUT_ID** is the column name **_id**.

As such a match for the WHERE clause will never be made as the **_id** column MUST be an integer (long in java speak as it's up to 64 bit signed integer) as the column is an alias of the **rowid**.

Instead you need to have something like

`selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(the_id_that_you_are_looking_for)};`

- **the_id_that_you_are_looking_for** would be a long (could be int but should rightfully be long) that is passed/obtained from where you are invoking the query e.g. in an activity.

### After Question edited.

Assuming that the other queires for the other cases work then perhaps use :-

```
    case WORkOUT_EXERCISE:

        String table = WorkoutContract.WorkoutEntry.TABLE_NAME_EXERCISES +
            " INNER JOIN " + WorkoutContract.WorkoutEntry.TABLE_NAME_WORKOUT +
            " ON " + WorkoutContract.WorkoutEntry.TABLE_NAME_WORKOUT + "." +
            WorkoutContract.WorkoutEntry._ID + " = " +
            WorkoutContract.WorkoutEntry.TABLE_NAME_EXERCISES + "." +
            WorkoutContract.WorkoutEntry.WORKOUT_ID;


        String[] columns = new String[]{
            WorkoutContract.WorkoutEntry.EXERCISE_NAME,
            WorkoutContract.WorkoutEntry.WEIGHT,
            WorkoutContract.WorkoutEntry.REPS,
            WorkoutContract.WorkoutEntry.RPE               
        };

        String whereclause = WorkoutContract.WorkoutEntry._ID + " =?";

        cursor = db.query(table,columns,whereclause,selectionArgs,null,null,null);
        break;
```

#### Notes

- This is basically using the query method as per the other cases as it appears that the underlying issue was that you didn't know how to include a **JOIN** (basically it's part of the first parameter).

  - the first paremeter although the documentations says *The table name to compile the query against.* [SQLiteDatabase - query](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#query(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) it is in fact the **FROM** clause and can be quite complex (as above).
- I haven't assumed that the other parameters could be used directly so it may well be that projection, whereclause, selectionargs and sortorder could be used directly (*so just **table** may be the only variable you need to concentrate on*).
- The above code is in-principle code, it hasn't been tested or run so may contain errors as a result.

Alternatively you could use :-

```
    case WORkOUT_EXERCISE:
        final String QUERY = "SELECT workouts._id, " +
                "exercise_name," +
                "weight," +
                "reps," +
                "rpe"+
                " FROM "+
                "exercises"+
                " INNER JOIN workouts ON workouts._id = exercises.workout_id"+
                " WHERE workouts._id=?";
       cursor = db.rawQuery(QUERY, selectionArgs);
        break;
```

- This assumes that **selectionArgs** is solely the id passed.
- This would be less adaptable than the former method.

Comment: @OmarCarino that's good, could you please tick the question as answered if you believe the answer help you.